# MSMQ ARCHITECTURE WITH DEDICATED PROCESSORS PER DATABASE

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, windows-services, message-queue, msmq

I have a web application in ASP.NET MVC , C# and I have a specific use case that takes long time to process and users have to wait until the process is complete. I want to use MSMQ and relay the heavy work to dedicated MSMQ consumer/servicer. Our application has multiple clients and each client has their own SQL database. So let's say 100 clients make 100 separate SQL databases. The real challenge I have is to make the process faster using MSMQ but task of 1 client should not effect the performance of others. So I have 2 solutions:

**Option-1:** Unique MSMQ Private Queue per database so in my case it will be 100 queues and growing. 1 dedicated ASP.NET console application that listens to a dedicated MSMQ so in my case it will be 100 processors or console applications.

**Option-2:** 1 big MSMQ private queue for all databases
                A:  1 dedicated MSMQ consumer per database so 100 processors
                B:  1 MSMQ consumer that listens to the big MSMQ

I want to stick with Option-1 but I would want to know is this a feasible and enterprise type solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have two questions

---

1. First, how do you `allocate a resources affinity to a processor` to `SQL Server`.

   Select the database in Sql Management Studio, right click and follow this..

   [image]

---

2. Clean your Database regularly

   `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;`

   `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;`

---

3. MSMQ, turn on `[journaling][2]`, but also consider another queuing process RabbitMQ etc, or write a simple one to *enquque* the jobs [sample from here](https://michaelscodingspot.com/c-job-queues/)

   ```
   public class MultiThreadQueue
   {
   BlockingCollection<string> _jobs = new BlockingCollection<string>();

   public MultiThreadQueue(int numThreads)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
       {
           var thread = new Thread(OnHandlerStart)
               { IsBackground = true };//Mark 'false' if you want to prevent program exit until jobs finish
           thread.Start();
       }
   }

   public void Enqueue(string job)
   {
       if (!_jobs.IsAddingCompleted)
       {
           _jobs.Add(job);
       }
   }

   public void Stop()
   {
       //This will cause '_jobs.GetConsumingEnumerable' to stop blocking and exit when it's empty
       _jobs.CompleteAdding();
   }

   private void OnHandlerStart()
   {
       foreach (var job in _jobs.GetConsumingEnumerable(CancellationToken.None))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(job);
           Thread.Sleep(10);
       }
    }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps :)

---

The question has been reworded, he meant sometheng else when he said Processors.

---

Update added a consumer pattern with onPeek :

**You really need to post some code!**

Consider using the `OnPeekCompleted` method. If there is an error you can leave the message on the queue

If you have some kind of header which identifies the message you can switch to a different dedicated/thread.

```
    private static void OnPeekCompleted(Object sourceQueue, PeekCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
    {
        // Set up and connect to the queue.
        MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)sourceQueue;

        // gets a new transaction going
        using (var txn = new MessageQueueTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                // retrieve message and process
                txn.Begin();
                // End the asynchronous peek operation.
                var message = mq.Receive(txn);

            #if DEBUG
                // Display message information on the screen.
                if (message != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", message.Label, (string)message.Body);
                }
            #endif
                // message will be removed on txn.Commit.
                txn.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // If there is an error you can leave the message on the queue, don't remove message from queue
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                txn.Abort();
            }
        }

        // Restart the asynchronous peek operation.
        mq.BeginPeek();
    }
```

You can also use a [service broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help and the sample. I will review it and see how it fits to my project.

Comment: I guess I was a bit unclear on the processors. By processors, I meant listeners or console applications that will listen to the Queue and process the item. The listeners will have business logic and other db operations as needed.

Comment: @user2272865 use the last sample, and  out your bussines dedicated logic in there, or a different `task<>` and invoke it as a task. If you still need help, just ask a new question and ping me, its easier to answer small specific issues.